# Как подделать заголовок referer при обращении к файлу (Видео)?

Tags: php, html, http, curl, online-video

Есть ссылка на видео файл с другого хоста- https://host-here.com/directory/720p.mp4

`<video controls src="Вставляем эту ссылку сюда"></video>`

И наблюдаем следующее, при запуске html файла не используя сервер, видео подгружается и играет нормально.
При открытии через например OpenServer, видео не подгружается, в деталях запроса выдает "403 Forbidden" (В самом плеере пишет "Видео в поддерживаемом формате и типе MIME не найдено" хотя если эту страницу запустить не через OpenServer, то все норм), через инструменты разработчика видны отличия в заголовках:

Без OpenServer

> Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5 
>   Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0 
>   Connection: keep-alive 
>   Host: 19-9.b.cdn13.com 
>   Range: bytes=0- 
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0

Через OpenServer

> Accept: video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5 
>   Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0 
>   Connection: keep-alive 
>   Host: 19-9.b.cdn13.com 
>   Range: bytes=0- 
>   **Referer: http://rn.com/** 
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0

С OpenServer добавляется referer.

В общем:

> > Можно ли незаметно использовать видео с другого хоста у себя на сайте? Как?
> >
> > Если это из-за реферера, как с помощью **PHP** убрать, подделать заголовок "referer" и сделать чтобы видео воспроизводилось на моем сайте (Вывести это все в плеер)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/video.mp4');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com/');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
```

Но при таком случае контент будет загружать весь файл

Comment: Спасибо, не совсем подходит такой вариант, буду искать дальше.